# How to set enumeration in proc print?

Tags: sas

The following does not work

```
proc print data=ch1.test  ; 
id=_N_ ;
where id >2 ; 
sum var1  ;  
run ;
```

`Statement is not valid or it is used out of
               proper order.`

I can create id in the data step

```
data test ; 
set test ;
id = _n_ ;
run ;
```

and then `proc print`

Is there any way to create enumeration directly in the proc print ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FIRSTOBS` as noted elsewhere is the right way to do it for this specific question.

For a more general answer, consider a view, or `PROC REPORT`, both of which can do what you ask.

A view is a data step that doesn't actually run, so it saves on time if that's a concern.

```
data print_view/view=print_view; 
set yourdata;
id=_n_;
run;
```

Then you `PROC PRINT` the view `print_view` instead of `yourdata`.  You could also do the filtering directly in the view (the `where` statement, or even a `first.<var>` type filter not possible in the proc).

`PROC REPORT` is effectively complicated `PROC PRINT`.  It can do a lot of stuff, but among those is the ability to create variables on the fly.

```
proc report nowd data=yourdata;
columns x y z;
compute x;
  rowcounter+1;
endcomp;
run;
```

In this case it wouldn't actually help (it's way more work than other options to filter out rows) but in other,  more complicated situations this sort of thing might make sense.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule with the SAS/Base procedures, you can't make variables in them (`Proc SQL` being an obvious exception. `Proc Report` too now I think). Procedures in other modules, such as those in SAS/Stat, are more versatile and many can create variables. Still, in general, the datastep or `Proc SQL` are where you make variables; the procedures are where you use them.

One could emulate your first 'proc print' though by using [`firstobs`](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000131129.htm). This specifies the first observation SAS uses when processing the dataset. Therefore, `proc print data=foo(firstobs=3);` should produce output as specified in your example.

It's worth adding that results from `firstobs` is dependent on how the data is sorted.

Comment: I wouldn't really consider `PROC SQL` a procedure of the same sort of things like `PROC PRINT`; it's a programming environment (like `PROC IML`).

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use a `firstobs=3` option on the proc print statement.